# Can't Display Profile Image, having path stored in database

Tags: asp.net, .net, imageurl

I am unable to display a profile picture uploaded by the user at the time of registration.
The image has its path stored in a database and the image is stored in directory /data/.
The imageURL is not working for me.
The code is: (.cs)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string us = (string)Session["userid"];
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {     
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cc"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select imgpath from reg where userid='" + us + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly what is the value you are retrieving, and secondly you are building SQL in a manner that is ripe for SQL injection.

Comment: What's the path of Image stored in database?

Comment: /data/a.jpg
data is directory in website

RubbleFord - i am retrieving url of the image stored which is /data/a.jpg in database.

Comment: Does the site run at the root? As I don't know what your writing the site in I can't give an exact example bit try ~/Data/a.jpg

Comment: Thanks dude :)
it works adding '~' before the path...

'code' 
while (dr.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                
                    String ss = dr[1].ToString();
                    Image1.ImageUrl ="~"+ ss;
            }
            con.Close();